# Windows 7 freeze after wake up from stand-by or hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-7, freeze

Not sure why my HP Pavilion m9300t wakes up itself during the nights or the day time when I am at work, it has been like this for a long time. It wakes up and go back to stand-by after a while.

However it starts to freeze after wakes up itself from either stand-by or hibernation. I cannot see any useful log in the system/application event log. It seems the machine freezes before the OS finds something. I tried to ping the machine from my laptop and it doesn't response when freezing.

However, it doesn't freeze if I am using the PC, it can function normally for a whole day and night if I am using it.

Anyway to diagnosis the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a driver or bios issue. Try updating these to see if that helps.

This happened on my DELL D630 after I installed new graphics driver and continues to do so it may be a driver issue where Windows 7 just isn't fully supported or sumtin...idk